# Is there a way to make the footnote package work correctly with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I'm using the `footnote` package in conjunction with the `hyperref` package. However, when using more than one footnote per line in an environment (e.g. table, but also other floating environments), the `hyperref` package creates incorrect links (i.e. links point to the first page in the document).

Why do I want this? Because there is a (Word-)template for my thesis and my latex doc should exactly the same. Using hyperref is not required, but I'd like to work them correctly. Since I use different environments with the `savennotes` environment, a solution that works with all environments is required.

**Please note**: I don't want to use special packages like `threeparttable` or things like `\tablefootnote` because I need a solution that is applicable to other environments, not only tables. Also, I want to have the footnotes at the bottom of the page like text footnotes. Having them directly beneath the table is not an option (e.g. minipage).

In the MWE below, the last footnote in each row is correctly linked by hyperref, however, the others point to the first page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]%
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    My text\footnote{Incorrect 1}\footnote{Incorrect 2}\footnote{Correct 1} \\
    My text\footnote{Incorrect 3}\footnote{Correct 2} \\
    My text\footnote{Correct 3} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just about to write »Don't do this!« but then i noticed: Already told you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it. Depending on how your table floats the footnote counter get out of sync and the footnote text can end on other pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{hyperref}


\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-6]abc\\cde\footnote{blub}

\begin{table}[t]%
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    My text\footnote{Incorrect 1}\footnote{Incorrect 2}\footnote{Correct 1} \\
    My text\footnote{Incorrect 3}\footnote{Correct 2} \\
    My text\footnote{Correct 3} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

bc\footnote{bla}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Regarding hyperref: readme.pdf says about footnote:

> This package is not supported, you have to disable hyperref’s footnote
>   support by using option ”hyperfootnotes=false”.

Answer (score 1):

Package [footnotehyper](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotehyper) but read its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

please look at footmisc the multiple-Option could help to solve the problem

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/info/translations/footmisc/de/footmiscDE.pdf

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment, since the question is about the [`footnote` package](//ctan.org/pkg/footnote) and this answer doesn't provide much detail.