# Make footnote and fnpct compatible with color package?

Tags: color, footnotes, fnpct

I know it is not recommended, but I have been trying to have footnotes in table environment. And the `footnote` package seems to me to be the easiest way to do it. Unfortunately, I also wanted to use multiple footnotes from the `fnpct` package, which is normaly incompatible with the `footnote` package (see fnpct doc p.21).

After some times, I found out that I could use both if I load the package `xcolor` (or `color`) first. Multiple footnotes are created inside tables and marks are placed at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{footnote} 
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\usepackage[multiple]{fnpct}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c} 
    tabular\footnote{1;2;3}.
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c} 
        table\footnote{i;ii;iii}.
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The only issue is that, for a multiple footnote, only the last footnote is referenced correctly (in the example, only the footnotes 3 and 6 (iii) are properly referenced).

<del>Is it possible to fix the references of a multiple footnote in this scenario ?</del> Related to another issue (footnote package doesn't work correctly with hyperref, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194255/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-footnote-package-work-correctly-with-hyperref?rq=1))

Why loading `xcolor` package makes `footnote` and `fnpct` packages compatible ?

Comment: The `fnpct` manual says (section 7.6) „`fnpct` is not compatible with the `footnote` package“ so you should not expect this to work.

Comment: I know it should not work, I read the fnpct documentation. But it seems to work with xcolor package, and I would like to know why. Or is it not working properly ?

Comment: The `footnote` package is very old and unmaintained. It's very likely it conflicts with more recent packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fnpct` with the `tablefootnote` package instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[multiple]{fnpct}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    tabular\tablefootnote{1;2;3}.
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        table\tablefootnote{i;ii;iii}.
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't matter to you, the `footnotehyper` package supersedes `footnote`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    tabular.\footnote{footnote 1}
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        table.\footnote{footnote 2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The version with `footnotehyper` also runs smoothly with an up to date `fnpct`